# Use environment variables in my.ini/my.cnf

Tags: mysql, configuration, environment-variables

Is it possible to read env vars in MySQL option file my.ini/my.cnf, the way it is possible in httpd.conf and php.ini with the ${ENVVAR} syntax :

```
datadir="${MYSQL_DATA_HOME}/Data/"
```

If yes, what is the syntax ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not possible. I tried making the same changes in MySQL option file, but failed to start. But there is another way though.

Set `MYSQL_DATA_HOME=<some dir>` in the console. And in the same terminal start mysql not by `service start` but with this command `mysqld --datadir=$MYSQL_DATA_HOME/whatever`